# Google Maps Issue with clearAll

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I am attempting to write a knockout binding handler (when I say write, what I actually mean is adapt someone elses to suit my purposes) to help me work with google maps.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NJ2R5/15/

I have gotten it to the point where I can dynamically add new markers to the map, but for some reason I am having trouble binding the clearAll function to my map object.

```
operations = valueAccessor().operations;
            operations.clearAll.subscribe(function () {
                console.log('CLearing All Markers');
            });
```

If someone could take a look and let me know where I am going wrong, I would be grateful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that my issue was my own code, it should have read:

```
operations = valueAccessor().operations;
            operations.clearAll = function () {
                debugger;
                var bounds = map.getBounds();

            };
```